# How block clearnet in Tor browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-routing, https, clear-net

Some .onion websites contain clearnet links which sends you to https (or http) websites. I understood that https/http is lesser anonymous than .onion. How can I block in Tor browser all links that doesn't contain ".onion" ?

Comment: you'd likely need to write some extension or hack on an existing one to do so. theres no currently builtin method to do this. there is nothing inherently more or less anonymous about onion or non-onion connections as a client.

Comment: Google sends message on onion Tor browser my iPad is sending mixed messages or something . I am supposed to accept and agree with their terms then says Netherlands . What is their problem , since they turn my google sign in as a Constant refresh loop I disabled them. Why are they allowed in Tor onion browser and my my ipad